# App crashes: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, cordova

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

my app in cordova vue2.

i use cordova-plugin-local-notification version: 0.9.0-beta.2

App crashes (android 12-13) at runtime with the following error :

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags (PendingIntent.java:408)
android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser (PendingIntent.java:688)
android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast (PendingIntent.java:675)
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.Notification.schedule (Notification.java:209)
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.Manager.schedule (Manager.java:100)
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.schedule (LocalNotification.java:273)
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.access$400 (LocalNotification.java:60)
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification$1.run (LocalNotification.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

Comment: @Eric  this does not work